# Storing App Settings in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm developing my first MvvmCross application. I'm trying to store app settings with SQLite but I'm getting some exceptions and I'm afraid I'm missing something. Hope somebody can guide me on using MvvmCross SQLite.

On app startup, I want to retrieve App settings from SQLite. What I tried is:
    var connection = factory.Create("myAppDB");
return connection.Get(1);

At this point I get an exception because the first time the app is launched the AppSettings table does not exist.

If I try to create the table with:

```
var connection = factory.Create("myAppDB");
connection.CreateTable<AppSettings>();
```

I get the next exception: 
    "System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy"

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good:

```
 var connection = factory.Create("mydb.sq;");
 connection.CreateTable<TableType>();
```

I don't think the `System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy` has anything to do with the SQLite code you've posted. I suspect that is coming from some other part of your startup code.

If it helps, my standard SQLite sample code looks like:

```
public class Kitten
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}

public class DataService
{
    private readonly ISQLiteConnection _connection;

    public DataService(ISQLiteConnectionFactory factory)
    {
        _connection = factory.Create("kittens.sql");
        _connection.CreateTable<Kitten>();
    }

    public List<Kitten> KittensMatching(string nameFilter)
    {
        return _connection.Table<Kitten>()
                    .OrderBy(x => x.Price)
                    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(nameFilter))
                    .ToList();
    }

    // other db methods
}
```

I will post a full repo and N+1 video for this soon - in the meantime, the demo I did at Evolve is on https://github.com/slodge/DemoFromEvolve - it's slightly out of date in terms of nuget packages but the SQLite code in [DataService.cs](https://github.com/slodge/DemoFromEvolve/blob/master/Evolved.Core/Services/DataService.cs) is up to date.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. The exception was related with AppSettings type. AppSettings inherits from MvxViewModel. I have created a new AppSettingsEntityClass plain class with only CLR typed properties to store just the needed info and now is working fine.

Comment: If you need inpc in your appsettings, try the mvxnotifypropertychanged base class